# How do I prove that $|c| ≤ \max\{b, −a\}$ given that $a, b, c \in \mathbb R$ and $a ≤ c ≤ b$?

Tags: calculus, inequality, proof-verification, absolute-value

EDIT: I forgot to mention the second condition: $a \leq c \leq b$.

I'm taking a first-year undergraduate calculus course and I'm faced with this problem. I'm not sure about how to proceed without using examples. I realize that $|c|$ might be greater than $b$ or $-a$ depending on the sign of each term.

Comment: You should add some context, as the claim is false as stated.  Consider $a=b=0$ and $c=1$.

Comment: Is there some known relationships between $a, b$ and $c$?

Comment: As you have it, the $c$ is not related to $a$ or $b$ in any way, so there is no reason why the inequality should hold in general.  For example, take $c=10, b = 1, a = -2$.  Is something missing in your problem statement?

Comment: @avs Right idea, but incorrect counterexample.

Comment: Thanks, @AustinC.  Corrected.

Comment: @the_candyman YES. I already added it to the question. I'm sorry.

Comment: @avs I forgot to include the missing part of the problem, which is an inequality between a, b and c. Please check it out. Thank you!

Comment: @MaximilianoSantiago I think it is superfluous to say "depending on the absolute value".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $c \geq 0$:

$$|c| \leq b \leq \max(b, -a)$$

If $c < 0$:

$$|c| \leq -a \leq \max(b, -a)$$